# What's the best way to get a dynamic object from JSoN without third party libraries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, serialization

I'm looking for the easiest/best way to convert JSON to a `dynamic` object, preferably without any third party dependencies (for various reasons). Currently, I have the following, but it required referencing `System.Web.Helpers` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies`, which feels a bit nasty.

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var url = string.Format(GetBoardUrl, TrelloDevKey, TrelloTestAuthToken);
var result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
var json = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(result);
dynamic board = new DynamicJsonObject(json);

Console.WriteLine(board.id);
```

Without the `System.Web.Helpers` reference, I can only get as far as the `json` variable, which works, but I have to access properties from the dictionary (eg. `board["id"]`). I could live with this, but I'm not (yet) ready to believe I can't do this with framework-only methods! :D

Comment: I don't know if this is the same as your `System.Web.Helpers` solution, but it worked well for me: http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the only "System.*" JSON serializer is the one in System.Web.Helpers.dll.  But if you're just desperate to not use 3rd-party libraries, you could always write your own parser?  The syntax of JSON is [quite straightforward](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: Found this, single .cs file installable via NuGet - seems to work well: http://nuget.org/packages/DynamicJson

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do by not using any of the standard JSON packages? Trying to eliminate one of the most common points of DLL hell in .NET?

Comment: @ChrisMarisic It's not a requirement, just a preference. It's for a FogBugz plugin which gets loaded into another AppDomain (I think recreated on every page request), so if I can keep it lean and avoid a dependency, it makes sense.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny you create a new app domain on every page request?

Comment: @ChrisMarisic Worded that badly - I believe it's loaded into another AppDomain (by FogBugz, not me), but it just creates a new instance of the plugin per request, not a whole AppDomain.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny with that being the case you might be best off with ServiceStack's JSON, I believe it's supposed to be the most ultra performant of everything.

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want to use third party library but DynamicJson is the best library. Its simple & easy